# Extracting JavaScript object from file and serializing it to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a file that stores some JavaScript object. This is not a JSON object, its fields are not marked with quotation marks. A regular JavaScript object like `{ field1: 'value1', field2: 2 }`. Despite the fact that it is a JavaScript object, its structure is simple, and it can be converted to JSON. And all I want is to know how is it posible. Because `JSON.parse` wouldn't work.

I know I can use eval and add brackets `eval("({ field1: 'value1', field2: 2 })")`, but this solution looks unsafe.

---

The file looks like this:

```js
// ...
callSomeFunc({ /* object I need to take */})
// ...
callSomeFunc({ /* other object I need to take */})
// ...
callSomeFunc({ /* other object I need to take */})
```

Comment: Is this some dynamic/external data? or is it something you manually write beforehand?

Comment: What exactly you need? Please give some source to perform on.

Comment: what have you tried? how exactly does the source look?

Comment: Yes, it's unsafe. But unless you're going to write a JavaScript parser, it may be the best you can do.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs, It is dynamic. The file is changing from build to build

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk, I added the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is dynamically created by a tool you create/control, you could perhaps alter it to output proper JSON instead.

Alternatively, if you're 100% sure the data will just be a JS object and can't be malicious, you could still use `eval`, or add `module.exports =` in front of it and require it as a module.

As an extension on the `eval` idea, if you're using Node.js, you could run this code in a [VM](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) (more precisely, a sandbox where you block access to all globals) and that'll migate *most* danger. Doesn't prevent e.g. infinite loops though.

Otherwise, you'll need an actual parser. I'm sure there are JSON deserializers written in JS. You could alter those to also support unquoted object keys.

---

I basically wrote a JS object/value parser that might be exactly what you need:

```js
/**
 * @param str {string}
 * @param i {number}
 * @returns {number}
 */
function skipWhite(str, i) {
    let ch = str[i];
    while (ch === ' ' || ch === '\n' || ch === '\r') ch = str[++i];
    return i;
}

/** @param ch {string} */
function escape(str) {
    str = JSON.stringify(str);
    return str.slice(1, str.length - 1);
}

const VALID_NAME_REGEX = /[a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*/y;
const VALID_NUMBER_REGEX = /(0x[\da-f]+|0o[0-7]+|\d*\.?\d+(e[\-+]?\d+)?)/yi;

/**
 * @param str {string}
 * @param firstI {number}
 * @returns {[any, number]}
 */
function _parseJSON(str, firstI) {
    const _sdf = firstI;
    firstI = skipWhite(str, firstI);
    const firstCH = str[firstI];
    if (!firstCH) {
        throw new Error(`Unexpected EOF at ${firstI}`);
    } else if (firstCH === '"' || firstCH === "'") {
        let value = '';
        let escape = false;
        for (let i = firstI + 1, ch = ''; ch = str[i]; i++) {
            if (escape) {
                value += ch;
            } else if (ch === '\\') {
                escape = true;
            } else if (ch === firstCH) {
                return [value, i + 1];
            } else {
                value += ch;
            }
        }
        throw new Error(`Unfinished string started at ${firstI}`);
    } else if (str.slice(firstI, firstI + 4) === 'true') {
        return [true, firstI + 4];
    } else if (str.slice(firstI, firstI + 5) === 'false') {
        return [false, firstI + 5];
    } else if (str.slice(firstI, firstI + 4) === 'null') {
        return [null, firstI + 4];
    } else if (str.slice(firstI, firstI + 9) === 'undefined') {
        return [undefined, firstI + 9];
    } else if (firstCH === '[') {
        const arr = [];
        let allowed = true;
        for (let i = skipWhite(str, firstI + 1), ch = ''; ch = str[i]; i = skipWhite(str, i + 1)) {
            if (ch === ']') {
                return [arr, i + 1];
            } else if (ch === ',') {
                if (allowed) arr.push(undefined);
                allowed = true;
            } else if (!allowed) {
                throw new Error(`Expected ']' or ',' after value in array at ${i} but got "${escape(ch)}" instead`);
            } else {
                const [val, valEnd] = _parseJSON(str, i);
                arr.push(val);
                i = valEnd - 1;
                allowed = false;
            }
        }
        throw new Error(`Expected ']' to close array at ${firstI}`);
    } else if (firstCH === '{') {
        const obj = {};
        let allowed = true;
        for (let i = skipWhite(str, firstI + 1), ch = ''; ch = str[i]; i = skipWhite(str, i + 1)) {
            if (ch === '}') {
                return [obj, i + 1];
            } else if (ch === ',' || ch === ';') {
                if (allowed) throw new Error(`Unexpected character "${escape(ch)}" at ${i}`);
                allowed = true;
                continue;
            } else if (!allowed) {
                console.log(str.slice(i));
                throw new Error(`Expected '}', ',' or ';' after value in object at ${i} but got "${escape(ch)}" instead`);
            }
            let key;
            if (ch === '[') {
                const [keyVal, keyEnd] = _parseJSON(str, ++i);
                i = skipWhite(str, keyEnd);
                if (str[i] !== ']') throw new Error(`Expected ']' to close '[' in object at ${i} but got "${escape(str[i])}" instead`);
                i = skipWhite(str, i + 1);
                key = keyVal;
            } else if (ch === '"' || ch === "'") {
                [key, i] = _parseJSON(str, i);
                i = skipWhite(str, i);
            } else {
                VALID_NAME_REGEX.lastIndex = i;
                const match = VALID_NAME_REGEX.exec(str);
                if (!match) throw new Error(`Unexpected character "${escape(ch)}" at ${i}`);
                key = match[0];
                i = VALID_NAME_REGEX.lastIndex;
            }
            ch = str[i = skipWhite(str, i)];
            if (ch !== ':') throw new Error(`Expected ':' after key in object at ${i} but got "${escape(ch)}" instead`);
            const [val, valEnd] = _parseJSON(str, skipWhite(str, i + 1));
            obj[key] = val;
            i = valEnd - 1;
            allowed = false;
        }
        throw new Error(`Expected '}' to close object at ${firstI}`);
    } else {
        VALID_NUMBER_REGEX.lastIndex = firstI;
        const match = VALID_NUMBER_REGEX.exec(str);
        if (!match) throw new Error(`Unexpected character "${escape(firstCH)}" at ${firstI}`);
        const value = Number(match[0]);
        if (Number.isNaN(value)) throw new Error(`Could not convert "${match[0]}" to a number at ${firstI}`);
        return [value, VALID_NUMBER_REGEX.lastIndex];
    }
}

/** @param str {string} */
function parseJSON(str) {
    const [result, end] = _parseJSON(str, 0);
    const i = skipWhite(str, end);
    if (i !== str.length)
        throw new Error(`Unexpected character "${escape(str[i])}" at ${i}`);
    return result;
}

const data = `
[
    true, false, undefined, null,
    { a: 'hi', "b": 'ok', ["c"]: 'ooook', [5]: { [[1, 'b']]: .45e-2} },
    [{ nested: { data: [1e3, 2, 3.1415e+0, 0xcafebabe, 0o666] } }],
] `;

const parsed = parseJSON(data);
console.log(parsed[2] === undefined); // JSON.stringify makes undefined null
console.log(JSON.stringify(parsed, null, 4));
```

Parses the given `data` string as follows when converted back to JSON:

```json
[
    true,
    false,
    null,
    null,
    {
        "5": {
            "1,b": 0.0045
        },
        "a": "hi",
        "b": "ok",
        "c": "ooook"
    },
    [
        {
            "nested": {
                "data": [
                    1000,
                    2,
                    3.1415,
                    3405691582,
                    438
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
]
```

*that first `null` is actually an `undefined` but `JSON.stringify` converts it to a `null`.*

**UPDATE**: You can find the TypeScript source [here](https://github.com/SchoofsKelvin/random-snippets/blob/master/src/js-value-parser.ts), which has examples and some extra upgrades. No extra parser features, but an example shows how you can easily generate pretty "error previews" like this:

```
Expected '}', ',' or ';' after value in object at 110 but got "o" instead:
4|    true, false, undefined, null,
5|    {
6|        a: 'hi', "b":  'not' ok , ["c"]: 'ooook',
                               ^
7|        [5]: { [[1, 2]]: .45e-2},
8|    },
```

Comment: Thank you. But the documentation of `VM` says **The `vm` module is not a security mechanism. Do not use it to run untrusted code.**

Comment: @Yoskutik Correct, it isn't. But if you strip all the globals, so it's _just_ JS syntax (e.g. literal objects, function calls, ...) it should be _relatively_ safe. Doesn't prevent infinite loops though, and I'm not sure how easy/secure it is to even hide the globals. Just an idea. Altered JSON parser is still be your best bet I'd say.

Comment: @Yoskutik Wrote a parser that might suit your needs. It isn't _thoroughly_ tested, but it passes the given example data string just fine.

Comment: Wow. I didn't expect someone would write a whole complier for me. I thought you'd just recommend some ready-made package. But anyway thanks a lot

Comment: I know there are packages like `jsonc` that might (partially) help, but not too sure myself. Thought it'd be fun to write so I did. _I actually already have an improved TS version that can also print fancy errors with an arrow pointing where your syntax error is. Like I said, I'm having fun with it._

Comment: Added a link got my GitHub with an improved version written in TypeScript. Might be worth checking out, although it doesn't actually accept new/different syntaxes.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the use case you provided what you need to do is simply put quotes around keys of the object, if they are not present. Let me know if the snippet below does the job, otherwise just share more examples in the comments, we'll figure it out :)

```js
const str = "{ field1: 'value1', field2: 2 }";
const re = /(?<!['"])(\w+)\s*(?!['"]):/gim;
const result = str.replace(re, '"$1":').replace(/'/g, '"'); // { "field1": "value1", "field2": 2 }

const obj = JSON.parse(result);

console.log(obj.field1); //value1
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
JSON.stringify(obj)
```

it makes an object all strings, {"id": "1"}

Comment: It won't help. I already have a string. But this string is not serializable by `JSON.parse`